# Deploying a SQL Server Express LocalDb database to ProgramData folder

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, permissions, localdb

How do I go about deploying a database to the `ProgramData` folder?

I am working with SQL Server Express LocalDB. My steps so far are as follows:

1. I added a LocalDb database in VS2015 by going to Server Explorer -> Add Connection, and selected to add the `.mdf` file in the local directory.
2. I added the `.mdf` file to the project solution (is this even necessary?)
3. I set Copy to Output to true.
4. In Installshield LE, I add SQL Server LocalDB as a prerequisite.

This gives problems when I deploy the application to a different user: the `.mdf` file doesn't have modify permissions (duh!) so it apparently needs to be deployed to `ProgramData` (from what I read elsewhere).

I assume this cannot be done at stage 1. above, just by selecting the `ProgramData` folder when creating the database. So how can it be done?

Thanks!

**Update:** I am confused about the right workflow when deploying a LocalDb database with an application. I was previously using SQL Server CE, which didn't need server installation, connections and permissions, but needed to move to SQL Server Express LocalDb. This is obviously more complicated, and I have no experience with SQL Server (or database servers for that matter).

I have managed to find a workaround by copying the database to `ProgramData` and  manually setting the folder to give users all permissions, but I feel this is ugly. Is this how people do it? Do people create a local `.mdf` database file and distribute this in their install projects, or is the database file created programmatically by the application?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is this not a legitimate question? If I can improve the question, please inform me how.

Comment: I guess Local DB does not accept remote connections.